# Fetching logs from Office365 using Graph API

Tags: logging, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I'm looking for fetching logs from Office365 Admin portal, like security, compliance and alerts and I need to push into my SIEM. So I need write a log collector which will do this.

So All I  need is someone please help me to find how to fetch Office365 Admin portal logs via REST API (Microsoft graph)

Regards
Karthik.K

Answer (score 1):

[Alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/alert?view=graph-rest-1.0) from Office 365 (Default & Cloud App Security) can be obtained using Microsoft Graph Security API. For more information, please refer to [Common use cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/security-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0#common-use-cases).

You can also use connectors to connect Microsoft Graph Security API to a variety of solutions for [Security Incident and Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/security-integration) (SIEM).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Microsoft Security Graph API - so that you can get the Alerts, Secure Score etc. Please refer the related [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/security-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) and [samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/security-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0#resources).